# Testing CRM Admin API Swagger Interface

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I'm attempting to try out the new CRM Admin API located here: https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/swagger/ui/index, but each time I attempt to run a call, the response message is the same:

> "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."

What am I missing?  I'm assuming that whatever user I'm logged into CRM with currently in chrome, that will be the user context in which the admin calls are made, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: There is an input with an `api_key` placeholder...you can enter your api key there and then click on the explore button...now when you click on the `Try it out` button, you should get the right response.

Comment: Alright @Hackerman I can't believe I missed that simple field... Would you have hints for how I would determine said API_Key?

Comment: You can start with the following guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/online-management-api/get-started-online-management-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger API cannot be used to test out the services. To be able to send and retrieve data using the new management API you have to get a valid OAuth2.0 token (see the first two sentences [in the auth docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/online-management-api/authentication)) for a user that has the Dynamics Admin or Global Admin role in O365 (see the first part about admin roles [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/online-management-api/get-started-online-management-api)).

When you log in through the browser you only get a cookie representing your login session, and not an OAuth token. [Auth0 has a very good article](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/) on the difference between cookie and token based authentication, but in this case the relevant part is that they are not the same, and so you need to get an OAuth2.0 token explicitly.

What Microsoft has included in their swagger API is a field for an API key. An API key can be generated from an Azure AD App Registration (more information about how to generate keys can be found [in the AAD docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#configuring-a-client-application-to-access-web-apis)). Unfortunately, as I specified above the MSDYN365 management API requires the the authenticated client has at least the Service Administrator role for Dynamics. These roles are user roles and cannot be delegated to an AAD App Registration, you can only use App Roles for them.

That means you're between a rock and a hard place you're not authorized to use, so the "only" thing you can use the definition for is to simplify integrating with your own applications.